# Only first page of abstract is numbered

Tags: formatting, environments, page-numbering, abstract

I have a two page abstract, but only the first page is getting numbered, which doesn't satisfy my department's guidelines. I've been trying to fix this for a couple days and going back and forth my department but they insist that the page has to be numbered, and I can't trim my abstract. I'd appreciate any help I can get, thanks!
The environment is defined as:

```
\newenvironment{thesisabstract}
{ 
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \newlength{\myName} % width of your name
 \newlength{\hangBox} % remaining space after your name
 \settowidth{\myName}{\thesisauthorLname , \thesisauthorFMname ,\ }%
 \setlength{\hangBox}{\textwidth}%
 \addtolength{\hangBox}{-1.0\myName}%
 \begin{spacing}{1.2} % increase a bit to accommodate the underline
 \noindent \thesisauthorLname , \thesisauthorFMname ,
 \parbox[t]{\hangBox}{
   \textit{\thesistitle},
   \thesisdegreeabbreviation , \thesisDeptName ,
   \thesismonth , \thesisyear .}
   \end{spacing}
   \bigskip\bigskip
}
{
\if@openright{\mbox{}\newpage}\else\fi
\thispagestyle{empty} \pagenumbering{roman} }
```

Comment: Did you try `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of `\thispagestyle` (hard to test without a full minimal example).

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}` is only affecting the first page of your abstract, and `\thispagestyle{empty}` might be affecting the second page.  Have you tried `\pagestyle{plain}`?  And not calling `empty` until you're sure you're on the next page?

Comment: Thanks so much! \pagestyle{plain} worked! Thanks for your help and sorry I couldn't give an MVE

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.